# How to make a small, node-like circle in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on css stuff where I need to display a small circle type node to the edge of a line.

[image]

Comment: How are the large circle and lines being generated?

Comment: Line I already have it, just need small circle node css style.

Comment: what is ur code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got you fam.

1) Let's create some CSS circles. *Hella* easy with `border-radius`.

```
<div class="circle"></div>

.circle {
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**Look at this gorgeous circle!**

[image]

Now we need some child nodes. ***MOAR CIRCLES***! Also, we should start thinking about positionin' these circles. `position: absolute`? *Pssh*, You know it!

```
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle circle-small right-top"></div>
<div class="circle circle-small right-bottom"></div>

.circle {
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.circle-small {
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.right-top {
    top: 50px;
    left: 250px;
}
.right-bottom {
    top: 200px;
    left: 250px;
}
```

**LOOK, We're basically there!**

[image]

So, the edges? How do we connect those?!? WELL, we're tagged **CSS** and **HTML**, SO we're gonna do it the painstakingly way: GENERATED CONTENT!

Tangent: You can do some amazing stuff with a single div: https://a.singlediv.com/

I'm going `::before`, but `::after` totally works.

```
.right-top::before {
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 65px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -36px;
    top: 46px;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

Let's break these down line by line!

- `border-top: 5px solid black;` - Our circle has a 5px border. I like turtles, err - consistency.
- `content: '';` - Dur.
- `display: block;` - Cause, we wanna position it later!
- `height: 100px;` - One of four values I tweaked around with 'til it looked good (thanks Chrome Dev Tools!)
- `width: 65px;` - ^^^ ditto
- `position: absolute;` - Yup
- `left: -36px;` - So our border-top is connected to the circles
- `top: 46px;` - Same as `left`
- `transform: rotate(-30deg);` - etc etc

**DRUMROLL**

[image]

*OH DANG!* NEXT PLS:

```
.right-bottom::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    width: 65px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -86px;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    top: -14px;
}
```

It's basically the same as `right-top::before`, except we tweaked the offsets `left/top/transform` to get....this:

[image]

**BOOYA!**

Anyway, I would go with [SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55188389/1253479). Or, `<canvas>`.

Good luck.

OH, here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcb4ay0d/) where screenshots came from.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SVG stands for Scalable Vector Graphics`.
SVG defines vector-based graphics in XML format.

In HTML5, you can embed SVG elements directly into your HTML pages.

Here is the code for circle.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="transparent" />
</svg> 
 
</body>
</html>
```

**code explanation**

1. The `<circle>` element is used to draw a circle.
2. The cx and cy attributes define the x and y coordinates of the center of the circle.
3. If cx and cy are not set, the circle's center is set to (0,0).
   The r attribute defines the radius of the circle 
   The stroke and stroke-width attributes control how the outline of a shape appears.
4. Set the outline of the circle to a "border".
5. The fill attribute refers to the color inside the circle(I had filled transparent).